# Does nvidia-prime do automatic switching in 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, nvidia-optimus, nvidia-prime

I was using bumblebee for a while and have no moved to nvidia-prime. I noticed that I can change the GPU that I am using through the nvidia settings GUI. My question is, however, is if nvidia-prime is doing any automatic switching in 14.04?

If so, how can I tell? If not, any idea on when something can be expected?

Lastly, and maybe should be in another question, but is it still possible to run a single app in the nvidia card?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. As far as when, no clue but no time in the near future, if ever.

Would be a better thing if nvidia could fix the total lack of vsync in nvidia-prime.